# Explaining COUNT return value when used without group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count

[COUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns the number of items found in a group and by default it includes NULL values and duplicates.

The first two statements returns an error and the second two - `NULL`:

```
1/0
1/'A'
1/NULL
NULL/1
```

But wrapped in `COUNT` they returns `1` and `0`:

```
SELECT COUNT(1/0);    -- 1
SELECT COUNT(1/'A');  -- 1
SELECT COUNT(1/NULL); -- 0
SELECT COUNT(NULL/1); -- 0
```

The `NULL` cases can be explain by the docs as

> COUNT(ALL expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group,
>   and returns the number of nonnull values.

So, the are evaluated, they returns `NULL`s and as `non null` values are only count, we get `0`.

I am wondering why the first two returns `1`?

Having the values in a table, everything seems normal - error is thrown and no value is returned:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [valueA] INT
   ,[valueB] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([valueA],[valueB])
VALUES (1, 0);

SELECT COUNT([valueA]/[valueB])
FROM @DataSource;
```

> (1 row affected) Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 16 Divide by zero
>   error encountered.
>
> Completion time: 2020-03-22T13:47:44.5512536+02:00

Maybe this `1 row affected` is returned as `COUNT`?

Comment: The `1 rows affected` message applies to your `insert` statement. `select count(1/0)` is curious, though, I would expect a divide by zero error there.

Comment: oho! I see what you did there... `SET ARITHABORT OFF; select count(1/0);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When constants are specified in the `COUNT` expression, SQL Server can optimize the query at compile time an avoid evaluating the expression at execution time. The resultant value can never be `NULL` in the first 2 queries and will always be `NULL` in the last 2 queries.

Below is a snippets from the `SELECT COUNT(1/0)` and `SELECT COUNT(1/NULL)` execution plans:

```
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="Count(*)">
<Const ConstValue="NULL" />
```

The "1 row affected" message generated by the client tool (SSMS), reflecting the rowcount returned by the `INSERT` statement. If undesired, add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the beginning of the script.

Comment: That makes sense. You got this operator using the SSMS and the execution plan?

Comment: Yes, by showing the plan in SSMS and right-clicking to view the XML.

Comment: I get it. So in compile time, the engine is interested if the expression is NULL or something else. If it is `NULL` it is ignored, if it something else (event generating an error) it will be counted. That's why `SELECT COUNT(1/0)
FROM sys.tables;` is counting correcty.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the docs that you copied further, `COUNT(<expression>)` counts each and every *non-null* value. If you want to count all records in the group, regardless of the value of this or that column, you need `COUNT(*)` (or other equivalent expressions, such as `COUNT(1)`).

The expression within the `COUNT()` is evaluated for each row; if an error occurs, then the whole query errors. I would tend to consider `SELECT COUNT(1/0)` returning `1` a counter-intuitive behavior, possibly due to premature optimization (`SELECT 1/0` does error).

But in real-life situation, as in your script, you can see that [an error is raised](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=deb80a13a576c0c7944a56df51c7cc4e):

> Divide by zero error encountered.

**Edit** - testing this on other databases shows no consistency in the results:

- In MySQL, MariaDB 10.4, and SQLite: `SELECT COUNT(1/0)` returns  `0`
- In Postgres: `ERROR:  division by zero`
- In Oracle: `ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero`
- In DB2: returns `1`

Comment: I think the op has `SET ARITHABORT OFF` in effect. When that's the case then `select count(1/0)` does return 1.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, `select count(1/0)`  is always returns 1 regardless setting `ARITHABORT` ON or OFF, try it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: it does not seem [related to `ARITHABORT`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad63867143a0c112ccdf598ed6f6d20f).

Comment: I agree the behavior is counter intuitive but I wouldn't go so far as the call the optimization premature. The result reflects correct semantics of the `COUNT` documentation.

Comment: Thanks for checking other databases, too. It seems it's something specific to the SQL Server engine.

Comment: @gotqn: yes it really looks like an edge case. I would be curious to know if the ANSI SQL standard specifies something about this particular expression.

Comment: Many details of the ISO SQL standard are left to be defined by the implementer plus most DBMS products don't strictly adhere. I think the ISO standard requires a `FROM` clause in `SELECT` queries but SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Sybase, etc. permit it to be omitted.